# Excel: Unique codes referencing properties of each product on an invoice

Tags: excel

I have been generating invoices by manually inputing the information for each product.

What I would like to do is type in a unique product code (E.g., "01-A") and in the same row automatically return the color, size, price, etc. ("properties") of the product.

I have a separate "database" sheet with these data and the product code in the same column.

I have attached a graphical example illustrating this idea.

[image: Graphical description]

Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You need a lookup - in this case a VLOOKUP.

=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).

For example:
`=VLOOKUP(B5, Sheet2!$C$2:$G$50, 2, FALSE)`

Where B5 is the product code you enter, Sheet2!$C$2:$G$50 is the table with the product details on the other sheet, 2 means the second column (i.e. size), and FALSE to say only lookup if there is a match.

See [the Microsoft reference](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Sheet1` is as follows

[image]

Then, in `Cell B5` of `Sheet2` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A5, Sheet1!$A$5:$D$7, COLUMN(B$1)-COLUMN($A$1)+1, FALSE),"")
```

Drag/Copy this formula down and across (to right) as required. See image for reference.

[image]